# symfony2 - WI put my Model Classes , I coul not find it

Tags: symfony, model

I was using CodeIgniter as PHP framework and then I decided to learn SF instead of CI.
Because CI stopped updating new versions.

I have

-src
  -Post
     -PostBundle
        -PostController
        -CommentController
          ......

And I want use a mode named Post_model.

In Post_model class i want to use these functions ,

```
class Post_model {

   public function LastTenPosts() {

      $posts= $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository('PostPostBundle:Posts') 
                  .................. etc ...........           

   }
   public function MostPopulerPosts() {

     /*  I want to use doctrine in theese functions  */            

   }
   public function MostCommentedPosts() {       

   }

}
```

in Model file , I want to use doctrine functions to connect and get data from my db.

where should i put my Post_mode.php file in SF and how can i use doctrine in model. how can i include doctrine functions.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You should really read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't the good approach using Doctrine 2. You should consider decoupling the saving / data-stuff logic from your model as Doctrine 2 isn't an active record implementation.

Maybe you should then implement some DAOs and delegate them the process of saving / loading your datas / model objects? Then, you would have no direct EntityManager accesses in your controllers nor in your model and would be able to get your DAOs as services.